# How can I find my dotnet mvc Controller's ApiVersion programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm using dotnet core 1.1.  I have a web api with several controllers, which look like this:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/mycontroller")]
public class MyController : Controller
{ 
     [HttpGet("action1")]
     public string Get()
     { /* actual logic */ }
     // More actions ...
}
```

I'd like to have a special controller which iterates through my controllers and print out the version and the route to them, like this:

MyController -- 1.0 -- /v1.0/mycontroller

MyOtherController -- 1.1 -- /v1.1/myothercontroller

But I can't figure out how to access the data at runtime.  Thoughts?

Comment: I am quite surprised there is no more info about that in Internet. ¿Did you find a way to solve that?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being late to the party, but the way to achieve this is to use the complimentary [API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer) package for API Versioning. This package is most commonly used for Swagger generation, but there is no direct coupling or usage of Swagger. You can use the API Explorer to enumerate all your controllers as well as their corresponding versions and routes.

In your scenario, you would integrate the required services with:

```cs
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
  options =>
  {
    // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service
    // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

    // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
    // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
}
```

The controller you want to output the information should declare the **IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider** and **IApiVersionDescriptionProvider** services in its constructor. The APIs will be grouped according to the **GroupName** property in the format specified by the API Explorer.

That should get you started. Let me know if you have more questions.